# SimpleCursorAdapter is not populating ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

The SimpleCursorAdapter is not populating my ListView, no error, just nothing happens.

Could someone help me find the error?

1) Layout with ListView component (tab_frag1_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvVehicle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Layout to represent row (vehicle_row.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plate"
            style="@style/vehicleDefaultFont.plate"
            android:text="@string/label_text_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hyphen"
            android:text="@string/label_hyphen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/model"
            android:text="@string/label_text_view" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver"
            style="@style/vehicleDefaultFont.driver"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:text="@string/label_text_view" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

3) Fragment Class:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private VehicleDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);

        dbHelper = new VehicleDbAdapter(getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();

        dbHelper.deleteAllVehicles();

        dbHelper.insertVehicles();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllVehicles();

        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            String[] columns = new String[] {
                    VehicleDbAdapter.KEY_MODEL,
                    VehicleDbAdapter.KEY_PLATE,
                    VehicleDbAdapter.KEY_DRIVER
            };

            int[] to = new int[] { 
                    R.id.model,
                    R.id.plate,
                    R.id.driver,
            };

            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    view.getContext(),
                    R.layout.vehicle_row, 
                    cursor, 
                    columns, 
                    to,
                    0); 

            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvVehicle);
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            Log.i(TAG, "Cursor = " + cursor.getCount());



        } else {

            Log.i(TAG, "Cursor = " + cursor.getCount());
        }

        return view;
    }   
}
```

**Curiously:**

My cursor contains an _id field.

I doublechecked my cursor and it has 7 rows.

07-21 01:30:22.215: I/ Cursor = 7

I tried using the layout to the generic android list layout, but nothing doing :(

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    view.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    cursor, 
                    columns, 
                    to,
                    0);
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextViews` that you have defined in `vehical_row.xml`: @+id/plate, @+id/hyphen, @+id/model and @+id/driver are all missing the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` attributes. These are required.

For now, set these attributes as "wrap_content". For example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/plate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/vehicleDefaultFont.plate"
        android:text="@string/label_text_view" />
```

Do the above for the other three as well. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem at XMl. Check id of your listview.

```
android:id="@+android:id/mainListView">
```